# Connect to port-forwarded Postgresql instance in Kubernetes from local Docker container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, portforwarding

I have a Django application that talks to a Postgresql database running in a remote Kubernetes cluster. There is a `docker-compose.yml` file for local development. For Kubernetes deployment, I have a simple `deployment.yaml` file for the Django Application and I'm using the helm chart from bitnami for Postgresql deployment.

I want to be able to connect to the Postgresql instance from within the Docker container running the Django API. Now, when I do a port-forward to the Postgresql instance I can connect to the database from my local machine using `psql` or other tools. From what I've found, to be able to access services running on localhost from within a container, you need to access it through `host.docker.internal`.

I've added the `extra_hosts` parameter in my docker compose file and can access services running on my local machine just fine. However, I can't connect to the port-forwarded Postgresql instance from within the Django API container. It seems that I can't connect to any port-forwarded service from the container this way. Am I doing something wrong or is this the expected behavior?

Comment: I'm a little confused by where the port-forward comes into it, and what "localhost" is.  From the Pod running the Django application (its own "localhost") you should be able to directly connect to the PostgreSQL database's Service by DNS name; you don't need a port-forward or to call out to the node at all.

Comment: I've edited the question. Basically, I'm trying to access the database running in a remote Kubernetes cluster from my local machine within a Docker container. If I run `kubectl port-forward postgres-pod 5432:5432`, I'm able to access the database using `psql` from the local machine. But if I run the same command from within the docker compose project using `host.docker.internal` as the address, it says that the service is not running.

Comment: What is the host OS on the system running the Docker container?  Can you migrate the Django application to also run in the Kubernetes cluster (you briefly mention it already has a Deployment)?

Comment: Since the mechanics of host networking are different on Docker Desktop vs. a native-Linux system, I think [kubectl port-forward cannot be accessed inside docker container](/q/66459883) almost describes your question, but on a Docker Desktop setup, and it's the opposite setup (`host.docker.internal` _does_ work).  [Double port forwarding kubernetes + docker](/q/67836160) is a slightly different setup (the port-forward is in a container), but does its suggestion of adding `kubectl port-forward --host 0.0.0.0` work?

Comment: I'm running on Ubuntu 22.04 and without Docker Desktop. [The port-forward question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66459883) seems to suggest that the problem doesn't exist on a Mac. It seems like `host.docker.internal` is accessible via the container and that is precisely the behavior that I want.

Comment: The `--address 0.0.0.0` part did the trick! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kubectl port-forward` is normally intended as a developer or debugger tool; it doesn't see itself as the "normal" way to access services that are in the cluster.  One consequence of this is that, by default, it listens on only the 127.0.0.1 (host) localhost interface.

You can fix this, specifically on a native-Linux host not running Docker Desktop, by setting `kubectl port-forward` to listen on all host interfaces

```bash
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 service/some-name-postgresql 5432
```

If you're using Docker Desktop (as in for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66459883/kubectl-port-forward-cannot-be-accessed-inside-docker-container)) then everything Docker-related runs inside a hidden Linux virtual machine.  For calls out of that VM, whether to `host.docker.internal` or to the broader Internet, Docker Desktop needs to run a proxy to forward those requests out of the VM.  Since this proxy is on the host, it can also reach things that listen on 127.0.0.1.  (This is also related to host networking not working inside the container: the "host" is actually the Linux VM.)

But if you're using the core Docker engine directly on a native-Linux host, Docker just uses the Linux iptables subsystem to forward packets around.  If you look around with debugging tools, `docker network inspect` might show you that the Compose `default` network is 172.18.0.0/16, and on the host there might be a `docker1` interface with IPv4 address 172.18.0.1 on that network.

This means, from a Unix networking point of view, that the request is coming from the `docker1` interface, but the `kubectl port-forward` is bound only to the `lo0` (localhost) interface.  It doesn't match, and that's why you get a "connection refused" error.  Changing the port-forward to listen on all interfaces removes this restriction.